# Seeking Icon library for custom GIS software?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, image, png, jpg

I am building a desktop application and currently utilizing a mix of icons for pan, select, zoom, attribute table, etc that have been randomly taken from the internet and modified.

The overall look is very messy and not that intuitive to our non-technical users so 
I am hoping to find a set of icons that have a homogeneous look to them.

My team has a small budget to spend on buying a set of icons but, if they exist, we would prefer to use free open source icons.

Can you point us to resources for either paid or free icon options?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the GIS icon library by Robert Szczepanek: http://robert.szczepanek.pl/icons.php

Answer (score 1):

The good people at Boundless have built on top of the well known [Silk icon](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) set to make a set of GIS specific icons called [GeoSilk](http://projects.opengeo.org/geosilk/).

You can download them from the [SVN repository](http://svn.opengeo.org/geosilk/trunk/).